When sending an API to Spring boot WAS using Postman, there is a problem in the process of receiving JWT bearer token authentication
Environment

My WAS is made by Spring boot 3, and user spring JWT, spring Security.
I use swagger to test normal json request API
But when I test multipart-form request API  I use Postman

Problem

At localhost, there is no any problem both swagger and postman
But in my AWS EC2 WAS, there is a serious problem to test my server with postman

This below captures shows problem which I have suffered in postman

simple API test with swagger


same API with same token in postman


cURL(which is same in swagger) exec result in postman


cURL exec result in mac terminal



The point is when I use postman, the 401 unauthorize raises in spring security filter even though the token what postman sent is right token and it successfully operated in swagger-ui or mac terminal or anyway.

Plus I found something strange in postman header setting(I thing maybe this is chore thing about this problem)
(when I uncheck 'host' setting in postman)


I have no idea to solve this problem. I think myself that I am pretty used to developing WAS and that's infra in spring boot & AWS, but in this problem, I don't even know how to find Google keywords for this problem. I tried Googling the question I asked using various keywords, asked about LLMs such as GPT 4-o, and asked people I know, but it didn't work.
If there is anyone who has solved the same problem, please give me some advice. Due to this issue, we have been conducting multipart-form API testing by asking FE team members for almost several months.

On the Authorization tab you should choose Bearer Token and then enter the Token on the right in the box. It will be sent in the header. Have you done this? Not clear from your screen shots.

what is a WAS ?
